# Using quantifiers to express this sentence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

These are from a study guide, just checking my work.

Let $F(x,y)$ be the statement "$x$ and $y$ are friends." where the domains consists of all people in the class. Use quantifiers to express the following:

A.) "There exists some student in this class who is friends with all of the others."

$\exists x \forall y F(x,y) $

B.) "All students in this class must have at least one friend."

$\forall x \exists y F(x,y)$

C.) "There exists some students in this class whose friends are not friends with each other."

$\exists x \exists y \neg F(x,y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers to (a) and (b) are correct.

Your answer to (c) says: there exist two people in the class who are not friends. This is not the same as what the original statement means; but you're very close to having the right answer.

Break it down:

- There exists a student, say $x$...
- ...and given any of this student's friends, say $y$ and $z$, i.e. $F(x,y)$ and $F(x,z)$...
- ...these friends are not friends with each other, i.e. $\neg F(y,z)$.

Can you see how to put this together?

Comment: (Also $y\neq z$!! Unless $x$ is friend with people who loathe themselves... :-))

Comment: @AsafKaragila: That would make the most sense... I'll let the OP make the judgement. I don't really like these 'friends' examples that tend to come up because they lead to irrelevant questions like 'is a person their own friend?'.

Comment: Note that in @Asaf's answer the final statement is supposed to be true for **all** $y$ and $z$.  The statement in the OP is not entirely clear but in my opinion Asaf is correct.

Comment: @David: You're right; fixed.

Comment: Clive, I strongly agree with you. I hate these examples from the bottom of my feet.

Comment: @Asaf: Do the bottoms of your feet have bottoms? Are they their own bottoms, or do we have an infinite descent of bottoms of bottoms? And if we do, what are we to make of it if your feet have some non-standard bottoms?

Comment: @Malice: The bottom of the foot is called sole. My feet, like yours, have soles. In fact, the infinite descent would be when someone has feet without soles. That would be the non-standard case.

Comment: Yes, it was a joke...

Answer (score 2):

The first two are correct, the third is wrong.

The third sentence says that there is someone, and every two friends that someone has are not friends with one another. This means that there is some student, that for every two distinct students which are his friends, these two are not friends themselves.

(Note that the I require that the two friends are distinct, but this is not necessary if you decree that no one is friends with themselves.)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake at the last sentence. What you have wrote is interpreted as "There are two people that are not friends". But what you need is a person that will have at least two friends which won't be friends with each other. So actually, you want $\exists x\exists y\exists z(F(x,y)\wedge F(x,z)\wedge(\neg F(y,z)))$.

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I misunderstood the third sentence.