# Boolean Queries in First Order Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, first-order-logic

I understand first order logic and how its constructed but I have some trouble understanding how the following statement and its FO query are formed.

This is from a book.

```
Size n = the set of graphs of size n;
```

The FO Query of size 2 then is :

```
∃x∃y(x ̸ = y) ∧ ¬∃x∃y∃z(x ̸ = y ∧ x ̸ = z ∧ y!= z)
```

Another Example :

```
Diam n the set of graphs of diameter ≤ n;
```

FO :

```
∀x∀y(x = y ∨ Exy ∨ ∃z(Exz ∧ Ezy))
```

Question 1:Would someone be able to translate what's going on here? Also is there a book or article which has queries of this sort that I can work on? I have tried searching for FO queries and answers but the queries i see are trivial usually and dont invovle this level of abstraction.

Question 2: Also I dont understand what 'E' in the second FO query is. Is that another way of writing an existential quantifier?

Question 3 : Also in equations like this is the negation for the whole of the second part or does it read there does not exist an X , there exits a Y and Z?

THANK YOU :)

Comment: No book to suggest. Just another [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662705/using-quantifiers-to-express-this-sentence) that might interest you. You can find more navigating through related questions.

Comment: I think that in the first formula something is missing : the variables before the parentheses are universal quantifiers ? in addition, some connective is missing in the right parentheses... The formula must be something like : $\forall x \forall y (x = y) \land \lnot \forall x \forall y \forall z (x = y \land x = z \land y \ne z)$ ... Please check.

Comment: Hi Mauro no the above statements are whats given in the book and I find it fairly confusing. Its called Finite Model Theory and Applications

Comment: In the theory of *graphs*, the symbol $E$ is a binary predicate with the following properties : (1) for all $a  \in G$: not $Eaa; (2) for all $a,b \in G$ : if $Eab$, then $Eba$. Its meanings is : two *vertices* of the graph (say : $a,b$) are connected by an *edge* when $Eab$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas are examples from Erich Gradel & Phokion Kolaitis & Leonid Libkin et alii, *Finite Model Theory and Its Applications* (2007), page 2.

They are relative to the collection $G_n$ of finite undirected graphs with vertex set $[n] = \{ 1, . . . , n \}$. Thus, each graph $G$ has a vertex set $V^G = [n]$ and an irreflexive and symmetric edge relation $E \subseteq [n] \times [n]$.

The second formula :

> $\forall x \forall y(x = y \lor Exy \lor \exists z(Exz \land Ezy))$

says that :

> "for all *vertices* $x$ and $y$, or $x = y$, or $x$ and $y$ are two vertices connected by an *edge*, or there exists a third vertice $z$ such that $x$ and $z$ are connected by an edge and $z$ and $y$ are connected by another edge".

The first formula is :

> $\exists x \exists y (x \ne y) \land \lnot \exists x \exists y \exists z (x \ne y \land  x \ne z \land y \ne z)$;

we must read it as : "there exists two objects $x$ and $y$ that are distict, and no more tahn two", because the second part of the formula says that : "do not exist three objects $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that they are all distinct".

It is intuitive that the last formula is true for all and only those graphs with exactly two vertex.

Comment: Hi Mauro thanks for the answer. In the first one, everything is an existential quantifier. and all the atoms will have X != Y or similar and its a conjunction. Does this help?

Comment: Great that makes so much sense now. So the negative sign is actually for the whole statement as opposed to just the x. Thanks again